# Using the framework of the problems encountered SharpArch

Tags: s#arp-architecture

I try to test SharpArch frame, directly in the provided example code to write some code to add test data, but unsuccessful, do not have any information to me!

```
ICustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository();
Customer customer = new Customer("Jack Chen");
customer.SetAssignedIdTo("JACKK");
customerRepository.Save(customer);
```

I just had an instance of CustomerRepository operation, do not understand why there is no new data on the data table

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because the session is not being flushed. On your controller you can put the [Transaction] attribute. This will begin a transaction and commit the transaction once the ActionResult is executed.